# AngularJS pass filtered value to scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good morning, i'm new to angularjs and want to practice it more, and here i have a question regarding a simple case while trying to learn to build my own angularjs webpage.

I have these two sets of data

```
$scope.data1 = [{ id: 1, name: "abc" },
                { id: 2, name: "efg" }]
$scope.data2 = [{ id: 1, info: "this is abc" },
                { id: 2, info: "absolutely not abc"}]
$scope.user = {
                id: "",
                name: "",
                info: ""
              }
```

and i have this input

```
<input ng-blur="passTheValue()" ng-model="user.idx" ng-type="text" placeholder="write name here"></input>
```

where i can write name on the text box.

my question is, how to pass all the value from data1 and data2 to $scope.user based on what input i have entered? For example, i write "abc" on the textbox, then my $scope.user will contain

```
id: 1, name: "abc", info: "this is abc"
```

i've tried to use $filter but i'm stuck at passing the value to the scope.

i'm sorry for my English, it's not my main language.

Comment: do you want it to be dynamic, I mean ,show the result while you're typing or after clickinga button or leaving the focus ?

Comment: i want it to show the result after leaving the focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the classical usecase for a filter: Do the processing of your data in the passTheValue() function.

```
this.passTheValue = function(){
    $scope.data1.forEach(function(value, index, array){
        if(value.name == $scope.idx){
            $scope.user = {id: value.id, name: value.name, info: $scope.data2[index] }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what OP has asked about.

Comment: but there's a problem though, the $scope.user didn't return to empty when the input is wrong. i tried to put else $scope.user = {id: '', name:'' , info: ''} but nothing happened.

Comment: my bad, i'm so tired i didn't realize that i add null inside the iteration. i'm sorry. no wonder nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input ng-blur="passTheValue(user.idx)" ng-model="user.idx" ng-type="text" placeholder="write name here"></input>
```

Angular

```
$scope.passTheValue = function(name) {
    angular.forEach($scope.data1, function(value, key){
       if(value.name == name){

          $scope.user.id = value.id;
          $scope.user.name= value.name;
          $scope.user.info = $scope.data2.filter(function(v) {
             return v.id === value.id; // Filter out the appropriate one
          })[0].info;

          console.log($scope.user.id);
          console.log($scope.user.name);
          console.log($scope.user.info);
      }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML , I've replaced the user.idx by name because you're searching by name. Sample on Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/bumDWC713dVWGnKoO5G3?p=preview

```
   <body ng-app='app'>
     <div ng-controller='appCtrl'>
        <input ng-blur="passTheValue()" ng-model="name" ng-type="text" placeholder="write name here">
     </div> 
   </body>
```

In your javascript, I add to simply search methods.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
.controller('appCtrl',function(){
$scope.data1 = [{ 
                  id: 1,
                  name: "abc"
                }, 
                {
                  id: 2,
                  name: "efg"
                }];

$scope.data2 = [{
                  id: 1,
                  info: "this is abc"
                 }, 
                 {
                  id: 2,
                  info: "absolutely not abc"
                 }];

$scope.name = "";
$scope.user = {
               id: "",
               name: "",
               info: ""
              };


function findIdByName(name) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i< $scope.data1 ; i++) {
      if($scope.data1[i].name == name)
        return $scope.data1[i].id;
    }
    return -111 ;  //Assume that it's an impossible ID
 }

function findInfoById(id) {
   for (var i = 0 ; i< $scope.data2 ; i++) {
     if($scope.data1[i].id == id)
        return $scope.data1[i].info;
   }
   return -111 ;  //Assume that it's an impossible Info
}

$scope.passTheValue = function(){
var id = findIdByName($scope.name);

  if(id != -111){
     var info = findInfoById(id);
     if(info != -111){
       $scope.user.id= id;
       $scope.user.name = $scope.name;
       $scope.info = info;
       }else {
         console.log(id,"Id doesn't exist in $scope.data2")
        }
  }else {
    console.log(name,"name doesn't exist in $scope.data1")
  }

 } 

});
```